# Convert C# Json format to Regular Json string

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm working in C# . here I often need to convert Json that is written in C# to its regular string format, Like this C# string to

```
            "{" +
                     "\"grant_type\": \"password\"," +
                    "\"client_id\": 2," +
                    "\"client_secret\": \"ClientSecretHere\"," +
                    "\"username\": \"abc@company.com\"," +
                    "\"password\": \"somepassword\" " +
             "}";
```

its regular string equivalent

```
  "{
      "grant_type": "password",
      "client_id": 2,
      "client_secret":"ClientSecretHere",
      "username": "abc@company.com",
      "password": "somepassword"
  }"
```

I've searched a lot on internet but everyone is talking about the conversion from Json to C# or C# to json . Is there any good programmatic solution for this ?

Comment: Yes, it's called "serialization".  Don't create JSON by concatenating strings together.

Comment: There is no such thing as "C# format JSON".  The value of your string is already what you want.  You need to understand how escaping works.

Comment: Why are you even creating JSON manually? What a bad idea

Comment: This doesn't make any sense whatsoever. Converting from json to C# isn't an actual thing. Json is a string.  C# is a programming language. You need to [edit] to clarify *exactly what you are trying to do*.

Comment: The C# code creates a JSON formatted string that is equivalent to "it's regular string equivalent", bar the typo. Think you've misunderstood something here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know what serialization is and I perfectly know how to do that ...!
@SLaks I know how escaping works . Please read my question carefully before posting comments.

Comment: @Will This might not make sense for you but over here it makes a lot of sense for me.

Comment: The problem is that your request makes no sense, the "regular string equivalent" isn't legal C#, you still have to escape things. First you would have to place an `@`-sign before the string literal to make it support linebreaks, then you need to double up (escape) every double quote. If you mean "prettify" the original string then you can do that using Json.Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "c# string" is not valid. But in anycase, this could just be a bad example and the process before getting built into that "c# string" could be some sort of restriction. Anywho - let's give this a shot:

```
using Netwonsoft.Json.Linq;

...

var text = "{" +
                   "\"grant_type\": \"password\"," +
                   "\"client_id\": 2," +
                   "\"client_secret\": \"ClientSecretHere\"," +
                   "\"username\": \"abc@company.com\"," +
                   "\"password\": \"somepassword\"
    }";

var token = JToken.Parse(text);
var json = JObject.Parse((string)token);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Should give out the "regular string equivalent" for you. If that doesn't work, maybe object deserialization will:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

var text = "{" +
               "\"grant_type\": \"password\"," +
               "\"client_id\": 2," +
               "\"client_secret\": \"ClientSecretHere\"," +
               "\"username\": \"abc@company.com\"," +
               "\"password\": \"somepassword\"
    }";

var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```